# (WebGL) Rendering triangles that are slightly different thru a single VBO

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, webgl, vertex-shader, vertex-buffer

**Disclaimer:**

I've stepped away from my personal R&D with WebGL and im trying to get back into the groove.
First let me make this clear, I first stepped away from this because I became very frustrated with trying to draw objects via a single render call. In short, I did not know how to do this from the shader perspective. So here I am now, trying to tackle this again.

**Scenerio**

My situation/scenario is simple. I have many objects (i.e. cubes) which I want to render in a single render call. I know I need to send this to the GPU via a single VBO. Each cube is the same set of vertices, but they can have different transformations as well as different colors.

**Question(s)**

Where/how can a non-engine programmer like me understand the vertex shader well enough to write one myself, so that the shader can draw all objects from a single VBO?

Right now I'm not sure how a vertex shader can understand which object it is "working" on (the VBO is a contiguous memory allocation for all of my cube objects). How does such a shader look like?

I sincerely hope this is clear and precise and that this question(s) is reviewed as valuable to this community.

Comment: What you're looking for is called *instancing*. It'll take some work on the client (i.e. JavaScript for WebGL) side regardless. With software instancing, you can reuse the VBO for multiple draw calls, but pass different uniform variables which you can use to differentiate them in the shader. With hardware instancing (search for ARB_draw_instanced), you make one draw call and differentiate things in shader with an ID variable or another VBO.

Comment: Posted as a comment, not an answer, because I know mostly mobile OpenGL ES, not WebGL. You'll need to do some further research yourself, but now you have some directions to search in.

Comment: maybe [this would help](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-how-it-works.html) and [this too](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfQ8rKGTVlg#t=14m27s)? The shaders in [this sample](http://boombambeat.googlecode.com/git/index.html) might help too or [this one](http://alteredqualia.com/three/examples/webgl_cubes.html)

Comment: @rickster is correct -- you want to create multiple *instances* of your one cube. The cube geometry is defined in its own local coordinate system and a transformation is stored in a uniform variable that is used by the vertex shader to transform the cube. You can render a whole bunch of cubes this way. The client still needs to make a separate call to draw (e.g., `gl.drawArrays`) and set up the uniform variable for each primitive defining the cube. I can give a more detailed example if you would like.

Comment: Ok, I shall look into "instancing". But recently my research has led me to believe that making a single draw call using a big VBO which contains all of my identical meshed objects is the way to go.

Comment: @wcochran. I believe what you explained is what I need to do. Fortunately I have a unique instance per cube object. The part I need help with is how to pack the objects into a single buffer and how the vertex shader processes this buffer.

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar If all the objects are truly cubes and they just have different sizes, orientations, positions, colors, textures, etc... then create multiple *instances* of one cube. If they are *not* all cubes -- different geometric objects -- then you need different geometry. If you have different geometry that you want to render in a *single call* (e.g., one `gl.drawArrays`) call, then you can connect all the geometry (e.g., made of triangles) into one object with (invisible/zero-area) degenerate triangles.

Comment: As described, im working with all cubes. Each cube is its own instance (it has its own set of vertices... etc). Now, I understand these all needs to pushed to a VBO. In other words I understand the theory, but I don't know what how to achieve this at the technical level.

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar I'm having the exact same issue, I'm trying to implement instancing in RAW WebGL (not three.js) without the use of extensions, I have seen examples of instancing but in programs that a very complex (3D cube composed of tiny 3D spinning cubes). Does anyone know of a super basic example (JSFiddle) of instancing where only 2 or 3 cubes are instanced. any help would be greatly appreciated.